# Error in method declaration

Tags: java, arrays, methods, declaration, average

I am writing a program to find the average of an array as well as numbers larger than that average. I am trying to write this all in a method. However, I'm having a problem with the method declaration as I am being told that what I have is an illegal expression. What am I doing wrong?

```
public class Average {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);





public double average(double[] number) {

    int x = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double[] numberList = new double[10]; //array to hold all numbers
    double[] largerList = new double[10]; //array to hold numbers greater than the average
    double[] smallerList = new double[10];

    int averageIndex = 0;
    int largerIndex = 0;
    int smallerIndex = 0;
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have a method declared inside a method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Average {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}


public double average(double[] number) {

    int x = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double[] numberList = new double[10]; //array to hold all numbers
    double[] largerList = new double[10]; //array to hold numbers greater than the average
    double[] smallerList = new double[10];

    int averageIndex = 0;
    int largerIndex = 0;
    int smallerIndex = 0;
    ... More code ...
}
```

AS shown above close the main method block and then declare a new method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fragment is missing the closing brace for the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: A method is like passing control to some other person which will do certain types of action,by declaring it inside a method it's like calling the same method again and again 
In case of Java it has main method and all utility methods to do things for you.In your case 

public class Average(){
// your main function starts here 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    // you can ideally call your average method from here 
    // Your method definition and declaration shouldn't be here
}//end of main method 

public double average(double[] number) {

    int x = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    double[] numberList = new double[10]; //array to hold all numbers
    double[] largerList = new double[10]; //array to hold numbers greater than the average
    double[] smallerList = new double[10];

    int averageIndex = 0;
    int largerIndex = 0;
    int smallerIndex = 0;
}
}//Closing your class Average
```